# Power BI embedded hide scrollbar

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI embedded report that is always the full width and the correct height so that all the report can be seen. When I resize the browser window, for some browser sizes, a vertical scrollbar appears in the report page. When scrolling down with this scroll bar, there is no content.

Is there a way to prevent the scrollbar appearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scrollbar will not appear if you set 'View' -> 'Fit to Page'.

This can be done in Power BI Desktop and in Power BI portal.