# How to remove the PowerBI Embedded iframe scrollbar (JavaScript API)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerbi-embedded

I have used javascript API for embedding the Power BI report in an HTML page. The requirement is to set the height and width of parent (DOM) to 100% each.

Below are the HTML and Javascript code used for embedding.

```
<div class="basic-reporting-container settings-page desktop-view" ng-hide="isGridReport">
        <div id="embedContainer" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
    </div>

var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

                    var config = {
                        type: 'report',
                        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                        accessToken: data.AccessToken.token,
                        embedUrl: data.EmbedUrl,
                        id: data.EmbedReportId,
                        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
                        settings: {
                            navContentPaneEnabled: false,
                            filterPaneEnabled: false,
                        }
                    };

                    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
                    var reportContainer = document.getElementById('embedContainer');
                    var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

The report is working fine but a vertical scrollbar appears on all resolutions. How can remove the PowerBI Iframe scrollbar?

One point which I need to be mentioned here is that when I removed the right filter option of PowerBI (filterPaneEnabled: false) then the scrollbar start appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Duplication of:

[Power BI embedded hide scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103435/power-bi-embedded-hide-scrollbar)

The scrollbar will not appear if you set 'View' -> 'Fit to Page'.

This can be done in Power BI Desktop and in Power BI portal.